# Drawing faded lightmap in 2D polygon

Tags: 2d, sfml, shadows

I have been making a 2D visiblity algorithm by following this tutorial http://simblob.blogspot.se/2012/07/2d-visibility.html

I have managed to create the light vertices and it works fine when I draw it in a single color, but I want to use a shadow map to get "faded" lights like this:

[image]

Mine looks like this now:

[image]

where the blue dot is the light center and the green is the lighted area.

How can I "apply" a sprite to this like this one?

[image]

My code lies here: http://github.com/doodlemeat/bugfree-octo-sansa

Comment: Have you considered using a shader and pass it the mentioned sprite? That way you can read from the fragment shader the pixel color of the sprite, and set the gree area color accordingly.

Comment: I have thought about that, but I don't think it supports multiple overlapping lights.

Comment: In that case, you can just do a simple lighting shader that loops through the lights and adds color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the UVs from the (X,Z) or (X,Y) vertex coordinates of your light mesh (depending on your world setup) relative to the light center.

```
vertex.uv = vec2(0.5, 0.5) + (vertex.pos.xy - light_center.xy) * scaling;
```

Assign that fading texture to your light mesh and set the texture mapping to clamp (or clamp to edge)

Use the scaling value to control the fading distance.

Note that unless you want to add some 2D pattern to it you don't need a 2D texture for this. A 1D texture would do fine with the brightest at U=0 and darkest at U=1.
Where you apply the distance from center to the U coordinate (with scaling).

Not all systems support 1D textures. Alternatively you can use a 2D (N x 4) texture in the same way. It will save on texture memory access.

You can also calculate the color fade directly in the shader without using a texture.

Comment: Hi, how would I use just a shader to create the fading effect on the mesh? Right now, I have the mesh, and I want to apply a shader to it so it fades off. I have a position, radius, color, and power of the light, I was just wondering how to make a shader to apply to my mesh to get a good effect. @StephaneHockenhull

Comment: pseudo-code for a 2d light effect:

`vector2d v = current_pixel_position_on_surface - light_position_on_surface;
brightness = Pow(Max(1 - Length(v) / radius, 0), light_falloff_exponent);`

Where **_position_on_surface** could be in UV coordinates, world coordinates, or screen space coordinates, could be 2D or 3D.

**Pos( , light_falloff_exponent)** is there to make the fading non-linear when **light_falloff_exponent** is not 1.0

The whole formula is "improper" lighting but I'm assuming you want a 2D (ish) artistic fading effect rather than physical accuracy.

Comment: Right, I've figured that out; can you take a look at my current question on how to blend that color with the current texture color? @StephaneHockenhull